# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2=1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nx_k=0$ then $\min(x_j)\times\max(x_k)\le-\frac1n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Question is:

> $Prove\quad\quad\left.
> \begin{align}
> &x_k\in\Bbb R\\
> &\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2=1\\
> &\sum_{k=1}^nx_k=0\\
> \end{align}
> \right\}\Rightarrow \min(x_j)\times\max(x_k)\le-\frac1n$

I think this is true. And it seems that $\min(x_j)\times\max(x_k)$ is maximized when
$$x_1=\pm\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}$$
$$\quad x_2=x_3=x_4=\dots=x_n=\mp\sqrt{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}}$$

But I can't prove the fact that this is the condition that maximizes the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a = min(x_i)$, $b=max(x_i)$. Then

$$x_i^2 - (a+b)x_i + ab = (x_i - a)(x_i -b) \le 0$$

Sum for all $i$,

$$1 + nab \le 0\Rightarrow ab \le -1/n$$

Comment: +1. Brilliant. But you have to improve your $\LaTeX$ or/and $\texttt{MathJax}$.

Comment: Great... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A useful technique is *mixing variables*. I will just give a sketch of the proof.

**Step 1.** Prove the claim for $n=2$ and $n=3$ with usual techniques.

**Step 2.** Take three variables, say $x_1,x_2,x_3$. You may replace them with $\tilde{x_1},\tilde{x_2},\tilde{x_3}$ with the same sum **and** sum of squares (we are intersecting a sphere and a plane through the origin, hence we have a degree of freedom given by the movements along a maximal circle), by maximizing $\max_i(\tilde{x_i})-\min_i(\tilde{x_i})$. Study how the global $\min_i x_i$ and $\max x_i$ are affected by such a replacement...

**Step 3.** ...in order to deduce that it is enough to prove the claim for $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I think I understood. Let me try the way.